# my app is crashing and show this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

### This function gets variables from another file users.swift

### append data

```
func getData(salval:String )
{   self.tabArray.removeAll()
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    if salval != "" {
        ref?.child("Schedule").child("Codaphic").child(salval).child(userID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot)
            in
            if  let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
            {
                let user = users()
                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.tabArray.append(user)
                self.tableView1.reloadData()
            }
          
            
        })
    }
    
}
```

### This is users.swift

```
import UIKit
class users : NSObject
{   
 var cname : String?
var _logi: String?
var key : String?
var wname : String?
var address : String?
var endtime : String?
var _leti : String?
var starttime : String?
var date : String?
var groupname : String?
var month : String?

}
```

**this file is inherited with NSObject**
but when project debugging its show error

Comment: To drag along the entire ObjC runtime to save a few initializer lines is actually a bad deal  I'd prefer to update to Swift 4 and use the `Codable` protocol.

Comment: guide me please

Comment: Here are [many many related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codable)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)` it means that the variables in your User class **MUST** match the same names as the ones in your database. The safest way is to remove `user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)` and use:

```
let user = User()
user.cname = dictionary["cname"] as? String
user.date = dictionary["data"] as? String
```

etc...

Comment: user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary) not showing in xcode i was trying

Comment: This is a really good answer. May I suggest two edits: pass the snapshot (or dictionary) to the User class.. and.. set the values within that class? It will enable better handling of nil situations or setting default values with a nil-coalescing operator in case a field is not found...  self.cname = dict["cname"] ?? "No Name". It will also shorten the code within the observe closure and the error checking is handed within the user object. And the the reliance on ObjC setValuesForKeys can be removed.